# Is it normal for Windows to attempt to log on to Guest

Tags: login

Is it normal Windows activity to see failed logins for a Guest account (even when the account is disabled)? It appears this activity is observed approximately 5 minutes following a legitimate type 3 logon onto a Windows 2012 R2 Server. Here is a log snippet:

```
<Computer>redacted_server_hostname</Computer><Security/></System><EventData>An account failed to log on.

Subject:
    Security ID:        redacted_domain\redacted_user
    Account Name:       redacted_user
    Account Domain:     redacted_domain
    Logon ID:       0x5914698F6

Logon Type:         3

Account For Which Logon Failed:
    Security ID:        NULL SID
    Account Name:       Guest
    Account Domain:     redacted_server_hostname

Failure Information:
    Failure Reason:     Account currently disabled.
    Status:         0xC000006E
    Sub Status:     0xC0000072

Process Information:
    Caller Process ID:  0x2224
    Caller Process Name:    C:\Windows\explorer.exe

Network Information:
    Workstation Name:   redacted_server_hostname
    Source Network Address: -
    Source Port:        -
```

The login failure log is indicated in over 100 Windows event logs.

Comment: NO.  Not normal.  That is the very reason that this account is disabled by default.

Comment: Is there any "feature" of Windows that tries to log into accounts when another authorized user logs into a system remotely? The activity occurs when a user logs into a system, and the source user is the authenticated user's account.

Comment: From my experience, shouldn't be but lets wait for an expert to come along and answer that ;)

Comment: Please explain better what you are doing and seeing. A screenshot will be helpful.

Comment: I edited the post to include a log snippet and additional info

Answer (score 0):

Logon Type `3` means a network connection.

This may happen for example when an unknown workgroup\computer tries to access
a share on the server.

It can also be caused when "Everyone" is included in the shared folder's permissions.

In any case, this is coming from your internal network, so you are not being
attacked from the internet.

And yes, under the right conditions this is quite normal.

Comment: Do you have any insight as to why Microsoft thinks its necessary for some random auxiliary account to need a failed login to access a network share?

Comment: When building its network neighborhood map, a computer will verify access permissions to shares.

Comment: So this includes the Guest user correct? I know that logon type 3 will happen during network mapping, but why the Guest account?

Comment: Guest account is for access without entering credentials (credentials are a manual operation by the user).

Comment: Where do the mysterious anonymous logons fit into the picture then if the guest account is used for credential-less access?